# arrow direction in cell campared with another cell in excel

Tags: excel, vba

I want compare data in A,B,C,D and E columns in 2019 with A,B,C,D and E columns in 2018 in same row where be following:

1. if cell B4 in 2019 greater than cell G4 in 2018 that will appearance arrow direction to up in cell G4
2. if cell B4 in 2019 less than cell G4 in 2018 that will appearance arrow direction to down in cell G4
3. if cell B4 in 2019 equal to cell G4 in 2018 that will appearance horizontal line in cell G4.

For example: This image shows the results that I want.
[image: example results]

Comment: Check Conditiona Formatting rules. There is an option to show icons/symbols that does exactly what you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be resolved with conditional formatting technique, to apply the same please follow the following steps

1. 1.Select cell G4 and click on the conditional formatting menu (available on home tab)

   2. Select New rule option..
   3. Select first option "Format all cell based on their value"
   4. Change format style to icon sets
   5. Select icon style as arrow
   6. change the icon (Green upward arrow for max & red downward arrow for min)
      7.Select value type from percent to the formula in both place
   7. Select the B3 in both formula box
   8. click ok

based on the cell value the arrows will change
refer the attached example
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/knU6s.jpg)

Comment: it is very good..... Thank you Mr. Angad Gupta,. kindly , can me do it this, to cell by cell? or, there is method to do all cells ?